# Converting SQL column with XML formatted text into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a XML data column in a SQL Server table. There are more than 5000 elements in the XML. I intended to make a table out of that XML formatted column.

As far as I'm aware, SQL has a limitation that a table can only have 1024 columns. How will I flatten the file so that it may be used for reporting?

Comment: Have you checked the XML documentation? Tried using the [OPENXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-openxml?view=sql-server-ver15) function? An XML document isn't a table.

Comment: I'd recommend against `OPENXML`. XQuery is vastly superior.

Comment: 5000 columns would be a nightmare for both developers and users.  Perhaps (dare I say) and EAV structure would be easier to consume.

Comment: If your XML has 5,000 "columns" I doubt it's normalised. A table can't have more than 1,024 column but a result set *can*. Though if you want to convert the XML to tables, then you are doing to need to normalise said data.

Comment: Did you feel a little sick inside when you suggested that, @JohnCappelletti ? ;)

Comment: You can store the XML document using the `xml` type and use XQuery to extract  what you want. I doubt that any query would try to retrieve all 5000 columns. Any query that does probably needs to return the XML data itself instead of the columns

Comment: @Larnu  Actually no.  EAV is not evil.  Sometimes it is the prudent choice.  I just know many folks here have expressed their disdain for it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Yes it looks like XQUERY is the solution. But how will I be able to generate XPATH for all the fields to write the XQUERY ? I tried loading the data with Power Query in EXCEL but it is limited

Comment: For the benefit of 'Ron, select statements are also limited to 4096 columns. Ref: [Maximum capacity specifications for SQL Server (2016 and later)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)